# Database UML diagram relation

Tags: database, postgresql, data-structures, foreign-key-relationship, erd

I'm wondering why does colored relation types differ...
As I understand from my db structure, I can have zero or multiple values from `codificators_document_type` and in `document` table this codificator is mandatory.

The same should be with `codificator_document_source_type` but I can't figure out why relation type differs. :(

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE document
(
  source_id integer NOT NULL,
  ....
  type_id character varying(2) NOT NULL,
  register_type_id character varying(1),
  source_type_id character varying(20) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT document_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT document_register_type_fkey FOREIGN KEY (register_type_id)
      REFERENCES codificator_document_register_type (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT document_source_type_fkey FOREIGN KEY (source_type_id)
      REFERENCES codificator_document_source_type (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT document_type_fkey FOREIGN KEY (type_id)
      REFERENCES codificator_document_type (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION

CREATE TABLE codificator_document_register_type
(
  id character varying(1) NOT NULL,
  value character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT codificator_document_register_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE codificator_document_source_type
(
  id character varying(10) NOT NULL,
  value character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT document_source_type_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE codificator_document_type
(
  id character varying(10) NOT NULL,
  value character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT codificator_document_type_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Comment: I belive the above two are "one to many" relation, while source one is "one to one". maybe you have UK for (document.id, document.source_type_id)?..

Comment: @VaoTsun actually I have `CONSTRAINT main_data_file_id_main_source_main_child_doc_key UNIQUE (source_id, source_type_id, child_document)`. But how that explains "one to one" if I have multiple entries in ducument table with the same source.

Comment: it does not. along with `child_document` this UK does not restrict one to one. btw if you have several documents with same source type id, then maybe UML is just wrong?

Comment: @VaoTsun this UML is generated with Navicat Data Modeler, probably generated wrong.

Comment: Just a technical note - this is ERD but not UML diagram.